# MapBox Search Event

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am utilizing MapBox GL JS to display Pins. I am able to display pins on a Mapbox map, no issues with that. I am looking to add some custom javascript code based upon the users "searched" location using the MapBox Search input box they provide.

I have researched all of Mapbox documentation and have not found anywhere where I would be able to implement some custom javascript code based on when a user searches.

Has anyone else come across this before?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean the mapbox geocoder control?

Comment: No, I am just looking for the returned search results of what the end user is searching for. One i have the returned results I want to implement some custom code based upon that.

Comment: I just don't understand what you mean "what the end user is searching for". Are you talking about searching for a location (geocoding) or something else?

Comment: Yes. Say the user is searching for Dallas, TX. I am looking for a way to capture the search of "Dallas, TX" and return a Geoaddress or Lat/Lng so I can apply some custom code against their search.